# how do you mock out methods from the class you're testing in spock

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I have a method I want to test in my site

```
public boolean syncUser(username, password){
    if (getUserFromDB(username)){
            // do work
            return true
    }
    return false
}
```

How do I test `syncUser` and stub/mock out `getUserFromDB`?

I've tried everything including

`_ * _.getUserFromDB(*_) >> true`

But it keeps trying to hit the method instead of using the return value. The test case is as follows:

```
void "successfulSyncUser"(){
    given:
    _ * _.getUserFromDB(*_) >> true

    when:
    def syncUserResult = userManagement.syncUser(username, password)

    then:
    syncGuidResult == true
}
```

Comment: Cleanest solution is to move `getUserFromDB` to a separate class. If you really want a half-mock, you can achieve it using a `Spy`. See http://docs.spockframework.org for details.

Answer (score 1):

You only can use this statements on mocks.

```
 _ * _.getUserFromDB(*_) >> true
```

That means you would have to first use

```
def mock = Mock(YourClass)
```

In your case `getUserFromDB` and `syncUser` belong to the same class. In that case you cannot use mocks.

Here is want you can do. You can use the Groovys Metaclass to override the implementation of your current `UserManagement` instance.

```
void "successfulSyncUser"(){
    given:
    userManagement.metaClass.getUserFromDB = { param1 -> return true }

    when:
    def syncUserResult = userManagement.syncUser(username, password)

    then:
    syncGuidResult == true
}
```

Please find a simple example how to override existing methods using Groovy Magic :)

```
class Person {    
    String sayHello() { 'Foo' }
}

def a = new Person()
def b = new Person()

println a.sayHello()
println b.sayHello()

a.metaClass.sayHello = { 'Bar' }

println a.sayHello()
println b.sayHello()
```

This will result in the following output:

```
Foo
Foo
Bar
Foo
```

Comment: I'd also add that it's good idea to move `getUserFromDB()` method to a separate class - it's seems to violate SRP. Then, there won't be any problems with mocking single field.

Comment: @Opal I have multiple cases where I use getUserFromDB so instead of duplicating code I have it in its own method.

Comment: But you need to move that method to a different class in order to mock it with Spock

Comment: I don't see/get SRP violations here. The class is called 'userManagement' and that's what it's doing. Creating another class (and another mental hop when viewing the code) to do one little thing to address a limitation of the unit testing framework seems screwy.